# Return complete profile from an updated user via claims WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

My setup for testing is with SimpleSAMLphp as the SP and WSO2 Identity Server as the IdP, with a 3rd party IdP as the federated IdP - this IdP returns a user ID in its claims and is Provisioned to the WSO2 IS user store.

I then update this profile manually (to be updated via API at a later date) to include the users email address for example.

Now when the user authorizes themselves again through this flow I want to receive all the profile (eg. the new email address) in the claims within the SAML response.

How can this work?

Use case: we have 5 applications and we want to share profiles of our users between them and they use the UserStore within IS as the master, Update it with an API and on a SAML SSO request the IS should return the latest user profile (as claims?) to the SP/Application - this for new applications will generate the new user profile with the latest details - as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to enable "Enable Attribute Profile" in SAML SSO configuration and configure claims you want to be returned in "Claim Configuration" of the Service Provider.

Here's my [blog post](http://blog.farazath.com/2016/09/configuring-wso2-identity-server-to.html) that walks you through the steps with screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it seems its not working for me.
The user logs in with a IdP and is added to the user store, I update their details email etc, and then next time they login the SP doesnt get these new claims/attributes back? Any idea, i have setup as you have explained.

Comment: Can you share screenshots of your SP configuration (Inbound SAML, claims config) and the federated IDP configuration?

Comment: SP: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9w44zQMPN_bb1FRM0g1RUVTT0k
IDP: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9w44zQMPN_bcF9ZZHFKdW9IYU0 - You will notice we do not have any claims as it sends back the userID only via a subject ID

Also I am using a mysql database as the primary user store and updating the users default profile

Comment: Any ideas? I hope you can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'claim configuration' of the Service Provider configuration in Identity Server. There you can add the particular user claims that you need to retrieve in SAML assertion as the requested claims. A detailed explanation can be found in [1].

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/08/retrieving-user-claims-in-saml-response.html

Comment: Still no luck, as below I am adding details into the user profile and they are not being returned in the claim, any idea?

Comment: When the federated IDP returns the user ID, Identity Server has to capture it for identifying the user that is already provisioned. For that, you need to set claim configuration inside the IDP configuration. Above I had mentioned only SP configuration. Can you go through [1] which explains a similar scenario and map IDP claim configuration and see.

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/03/facebook-api-v25-as-federated.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have done that, but it seems still nothing, my IdP does not return any "claims" but only the userID within the subject attribute, IS is storing this as 'name' and then i am updating this record and loggin in again and the new claims are not coming through at all. any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? I hope you can help! :)